# (cocos2d-x 3.2 / xcode 6) How to open cpp-tests for iOS, no project file present

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Cocos2d-x 3.2 -- went to open `tests/cpp-tests/proj.ios` (using xcode 6) but don't see a `.xcodeproj` file in there, the individual header and cpp files are though.

How do I generate a `.xcodeproj` file for these tests (cmake??, don't know what that is) or is there something else I'm missing?  Gosh golly, I hope this isn't a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

> https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x

Running Tests
Select the test you want from Xcode Scheme chooser.

For OS X / iOS

```
$ cd cocos2d-x/build
$ open cocos_tests.xcodeproj
```